# Chrome search bar hits server while typing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, google-chrome

So here's the deal: I have a user authenticated with OWIN, and when authenticated in this way, this particular user type is allowed to only see one page on the site. If they try to get to other pages, or even refresh the current page, they're kicked back to the Login page.

This is an AngularJS app, so it only uses MVC for the initial view. Consequently, if a user manages to get back here and is still logged in, I sign them out and refresh.

It all works fine, but here's the weird part: if I start typing in the address bar of Chrome, the server is hit (`HomeController.Index()`), which normally doesn't seem to have any affect on the client side, unless you sign the logged in user out in `Index()`, in which case once you start typing in the address bar, it kicks you back to the login page. Also, I see nothing happening in the debugger's network tab when this happens.

This behavior doesn't seem to be present in Firefox or IE, does anybody have an explanation?

Edit: To clarify, I have a breakpoint set in `Index()`, I click into the address bar, I begin typing (just one or two characters), the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Doesn't make sense that typing in address bar alone would cause a new request to be made without hitting `enter` or `go` button. Explanation could use clarification.

Comment: It doesn't make sense but it's happening

Comment: try incognito mode and try disabling extensions. That behavior makes no sense in any browser

Comment: Sounds like Chrome is pre-fetching the page it thinks you want to speed up perceived responsiveness.

Comment: I think Kevin B is onto something http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2014/04/30/unexpected-prerender-in-chrome/